# Determine limit of function of (x,y)

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus

I need help to determine the limit of this function:
$$\lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)} \frac{e^{x^2-y}\cdot\sin(x^3-y^3)}{x^4+y^4}.$$
I tried to approach from the coordinate axis and use Taylor, but I'm getting $(0\cdot (-\infty))$. Am I thinking wrong?

Comment: Have you tried to see what happen if you take $(t,t)$ and $(t,0)$ and let $t\to 0$ ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This limit does not exist. Take the line $y=x$. Then $f(x,y)=0$ across the line and clearly

$\displaystyle \lim_{(x,x) \to 0}f(x,x)=0$.

Now take the curve $y=x^{2}$ then the function becomes

$f(x,y)=\dfrac{sinx^{3}-sinx^{6}}{x^{4}+x^{8}}$. Using L'Hospital's rule we get:

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{3x^{2}cosx^{3}-6x^{5}cosx^{6}}{4x^{3}+8x^{7}}$

eliminating $x^{2}$ we get

$\displaystyle \lim_{x \to 0}\dfrac{3cosx^{3}-6x^{3}cosx^{6}}{4x+8x^{5}}$

=$\dfrac{3}{0^{+/-}}=+/-\infty$.

Therefore the limit does not exist because following different paths we get different limits.

Answer (score 0):

Let $y=x$,the limit is $0$.

Let $y=2x$,use series expansion at $x=0$ :$\dfrac{e^{x^2-2x}\cdot\sin \left( -7x^3 \right)}{17x^4}=\frac{-7}{17x}+\frac{14}{17}-\frac{21x}{17}+O\left( x^2 \right)$

You can get the limit is $\infty$.

So the limit does't exist.

Answer (score 0):

The factor $e^{x^2-y}$ tends to $1.$ It suffices to consider $$g(x,y)={\sin(x^3-y^3)\over x^4+y^4}$$ Let $y=0.$ For $x\to 0^+$ the limit is equal $\infty,$ while for $x\to 0^-$ the limit is equal $-\infty.$ Thus the limit does not exists even in the improper sense.